# Padding in query string of url

Tags: python-2.7, url, https, get

In cryptography, starting with:
'http://www.server.com/?tag=xx&uid=99' (for example)

a hash length extension attack attempts to append to the url with
'http://www.server.com/?tag=xx&uid=99%80%00&deposit=100'

where the the '%80%00' represents the percent encoding of the 'padding' characters used to extend the message.

I'm using HTTPConnection.request('Get', url) in python to send the request but I'm getting an invalid uid message. Does this mean that the server is treating the %80%00 as part of the uid value? Or am I encoding the url incorreectly?

Could someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this mean that the server is treating the %80%00 as part of the uid value? Probably. All depends on what the backend code does with the query string. Do you have access to the backend code?

Comment: @RedCricket, no I don't. Most articles I've read specify "percent encoding". However, they don't explain how the server figures out where the parm value ends and where the padding starts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the backend code. One possible solution is to append &uid=99 to the url being used for the attack to overwrite the invalid uid.

Ex. http://www.server.com/?tag=xx&uid=99%80%00&deposit=100&uid=99

The server then replaces the invalid uid with the valid one.